# Replanting mango plant and accidentally broke seed from root/sprout

Tags: seeds, mango, replant

So I was replanting my mango plant which is now about 16in tall and accidentally broke the seed off the sprout/root. Both sprout and roots are attached but mango seed is not as it was rotting. Will it continue to grow ?

Answer (score 1):

At some point, the seed has given the young tree all it can. At that point, the tree wouldn't notice if the seed disappeared.

I don't know how much your tree is relying on the seed at this point, but if it's 16 inches tall already, I'll guess the tree has a good chance.

Please leave a followup later so we know how things turned out.